# Learnyounode http server ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, http

When I want start my http server from this code:

```
var http = require('http')
var fs = require('fs')

var port = 8080
var fileName = "test"

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    fs.createReadStream(fileName).pipe(response)
}).listen(port)
```

But when I want run, I get this output:

```
  ✗  Error connecting to
  (http://localhost:25066/api/parsetime?iso=2017-12-02T14:50:54.063Z): connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:25066

  ✗  Error connecting to
  (http://localhost:25066/api/unixtime?iso=2017-12-02T14:50:54.063Z): connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:25066
```

What's the problem?

Comment: in the error, it says it's attempting to connect to port `:25066` but your server is running on port `:8080`

Comment: `listen` arg is missing

Answer (score 0):

`ECONREFUSED` most of the time means you are trying to access a port which is already being used. However there is something weird about your error because as mentioned above, you've set port `8080` to run your sorver on but the error shows port `25066`.